# How to remove a specific row in arraylist

Tags: java

How do I remove a specific row from an ArrayList as I tried to do it but it still shows on the ArrayList after doing it? For example, if I want to remove rollno: 2,BBB,14. how should I remove that from the ArrayList and not the other two. I tried to put itr.remove in the while loop mentioned below in comments, but still no luck, it still shows up in the array list and nothing gets removed.

public class StudentDB{

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Creating user defined class objects  
        Student s1=new Student(1,"AAA",13);  
        Student s2=new Student(2,"BBB",14);  
        Student s3=new Student(3,"CCC",15); 

        ArrayList<Student> al=new ArrayList<Student>();
        al.add(s1);
        al.add(s2);  
        al.add(s3);  

        Iterator itr=al.iterator();  

        //traverse elements of ArrayList object  
       /* while(itr.hasNext()){  
            Student st=(Student)itr.next();  
            if(st.rollno == 2){
            System.out.println(st.rollno+" "+st.name+" "+st.age);  
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }  */
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENter your id: ");
        int id = scan.nextInt();


        boolean result = false;
        while(!result) {
            while(itr.hasNext()) {  
               Student st=(Student)itr.next();  
               if(st.rollno == id){
               result = true;
               break;
               }
               else{
                   result = false;
               } 
        }       

    }
    if(result == true){
      System.out.println("Roll no found!");
      }else{
      System.out.println("Roll no not found!");
      }
      }
}
class Student{  
    int rollno;  
    String name;  
    int age;  
    Student(int rollno,String name,int age){  
        this.rollno=rollno;  
        this.name=name;  
        this.age=age;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
System.out.println("Enter id to remove: ");
int id = scan.nextInt();

Iterator<Student> itr = al.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if (itr.next().rollno == id) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think if we are removing element while itrating ArrayList using Iterator, it may throw ConcurrentModificationException. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Worth adding that it is recommended not to use a raw type *Iterator* as the OP has used.

Comment: @Sreejith If you do `al.remove(s)` in the while loop, you are right.  But `itr.remove()` is an Iterator's method to remove the last element returned by this iterator.

Comment: Didn't work, when I do that, it removes the whole thing instead of the row.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to use two loops. You need to call the remove method on the iterator as follow:

```
            while(itr.hasNext()) {  
               Student st=(Student)itr.next();  
               if(st.rollno == id){
               itr.remove();
               result = true;
               break;
               }
               else{
                   result = false;
               }
```